# I can not import the font in the app.vue file in the style section

Tags: javascript, import, fonts, sass, vue-cli

I wrote this in my app.cue file in the style section of scss. I can not import any type of font. How can I solve this problem. The font is in the font folder of my project.

myproject 
   | -src 
     | -app.vue 
     | - font 
           | - namefont.ttf

```
<style lang="scss">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'namefont';
        src: url('./font/namefont.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error in your console when trying to import the font? If yes, which error?

Comment: @ThomasLombart I have just updated the post with the error screen that is reported to me in the console

Comment: It seems Vue doesn't know how to handle `.ttf` files. Could you share your Webpack configuration or Vue CLI configuration (the filename is `vue.config.js`)?

Comment: @ThomasLombart https://pastebin.com/7A8i2BMh webpackconfig

Comment: In your [configuration file](https://pastebin.com/7A8i2BMh), you haven't specified how to handle `.ttf` files in your `rules`. You need to add `url-loader` for that. Something like: `{ test: /\.tff$/, use: { loader: 'url-loader' } }` should do the trick.

Comment: @ThomasLombart gives me the same error after the change you told me to do

Comment: It has to do with your Webpack config as you get a parsing error. If you can give me a CodeSandbox of your app, I can take a look, otherwise check that [link](https://www.chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack)